# Proguard not obfuscating any classname not method in it

Tags: android, proguard

I recently activated minifyEnabled in my project so proguard could obfuscate class names and methods, but after analysing the generated apk and looking at the configuration.txt file generated by proguard I found out that all classes are being added to that file with the --keep class annotation resulting in any obfuscation being made.

My proguard-rules.pro file is left by default with everything commented.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the release build for your apk? since minifyEnabled is set to true, you may have set it to true in the release build:

```
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

If you want to apply it to the `debug` build into your `buildTypes`, simply add it to your gradle file:

```
debug {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

Comment: yes, I've use the release build for my apk. Also I tried the same configuration with another project and it is working as intended.